# Authorization error through native facebook application

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

When you try to log in using the Facebook application, SDK returns error:

> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}

The error is not reproduced in the case of authorization through Safari, only through the application and not every time.

My code:

```
- (IBAction)loginFacebook:(UIButton *)sender
{
     FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
     [login logOut];
     [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"email"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
           [self showError:error];
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
           NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        } else {
           [LoadingView startLoading:@"" inView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] isProgress:NO showWithCheckmark:NO];
           [[BackendService sharedBackendService] fbLoginWithAccessToken:result.token.tokenString successBlock:^() {
                [_errorView removeFromSuperview];
                 _errorView = nil;
                 STOP_LOADING
                [self showMainVC];
             } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                 STOP_LOADING
             [self showError:error];
         }];
      }
   }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem in this way. Maybe someone else will be useful in the future. Minimum update delay helped me. Here is an example:

```
- (IBAction)loginFacebook:(UIButton *)sender
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logOut];
    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"email"]
     fromViewController:self
    handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            [self showError:error];
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        } else {

         dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             [LoadingView startLoading:@"" inView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] isProgress:NO showWithCheckmark:NO];
             [[BackendService sharedBackendService] fbLoginWithAccessToken:result.token.tokenString successBlock:^() {
                 [_errorView removeFromSuperview];
                 _errorView = nil;
                 STOP_LOADING
                 [self showMainVC];
             } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                 STOP_LOADING
                 [self showError:error];
             }];

         });

     }
 }];
```

}